# Dictionary Based Text CLassification in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, classification, keyword

It's quite a while now that I'm looking for a descent **dictionary based text classification** library in Python.

My use case is as follow: I will be receiving a long **`text`** which would likely talk about several things and hopefully mention some of a pre-defined **`entities`**.

```
text = "Yesterday, I ate a Yelow-fruit. It was the longest fruit I ever ate."
entities = {"apple": ["pink", "sphere"], "banana": ["yellow", "tasty", "long"]}
```

**Please note that spelling errors are intentional !**

My goal is to have a program such that given this text and the entities dict (which will change over time), the program should output **`banana`**. Hence, the problem can be seen as a **dictionay based text classification** problem where one will classify the text based on the **entities** dictionary.

The latest problem seems so standard to me but I fail finding a descent implementation in Python.

Of course, I can go through the text and count word occurences by entity and finally output the most frequent entity. But this approach is very simple and won't survive in real word scenario where the occurences would **NOT** be exact. I would expect a good approach to include some text similarity metrics and allow user to choose which pre-processings are accpetable (lowercase, stemming, stopwords removal, ...). How tokenization should be done ? Is there a **semantic** similarity or not ? If there is a semantic similarity, does a dictionay expansion algorithm is offered ?

So far, I've read this [R blog post](https://sicss.io/2019/materials/day3-text-analysis/dictionary-methods/rmarkdown/Dictionary-Based_Text_Analysis.html) which gives a starting point for a dictionary based text classification in R. This [datascience stack-exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/111912/performing-a-text-classification-based-on-a-dictionary) question seems to be related to mine as well. But none of these give a satisfactory anwser.

So, Is there any straightforward library in Python for this kind of task ?

Thanks in adance for your replies.

Comment: Nope ! It was a mistake, fixed ! Pre-defined dict is assumed perfect and is defined by "experts".

Answer (score 3):

You're asking for a simple solution while at the same time asserting that the problem is complex and that the frequency of related tokens may not be a strong enough indicator to always predict the right class. What you're alluding to is that you need to understand the context in which your related tokens are mentioned and for that, you will likely need a more complex solution.

One solution you could look at using is zero-shot NLP classification.

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model="facebook/bart-large-mnli")

text = "Yesterday, I ate a yelow-fruit. It was the longest fruit I ever ate."
candidate_labels = ['banana', 'apple']
classifier(text, candidate_labels)
```

The output is:

```
{'sequence': 'Yesterday, I ate a yelow-fruit. It was the longest fruit I ever ate.', 'labels': ['banana', 'apple'], 'scores': [0.6739664077758789, 0.3260335922241211]}
```

Edit:
To incorporate further information into the model we can expand the description of the candidate labels as such:

```
candidate_labels = ['banana yellow tasty long', 'apple pink sphere']
```

The new output is:

```
{'sequence': 'Yesterday, I ate a yelow-fruit. It was the longest fruit I ever ate.', 'labels': ['banana yellow tasty long', 'apple pink sphere'], 'scores': [0.9392997622489929, 0.060700222849845886]}
```

You can see from the addition of the descriptive words the difference between the scores of our two labels has increased.

Note:
This attention-based deep learning model uses embeddings to understand the similarity between tokens. Tokens that are close together in this high-dimensional space are proportionally similar in their semantic meaning. Even without specifying additional descriptive words, the model should be able to generalize because it contains knowledge about what a banana or apple is from the millions of text examples it was trained on. This is worth considering when expecting the model to generalize to more abstract examples e.g. wheree classes may contain product SKUs.

Comment: Could you maybe explain what this does in some more detail so it'd be a better answer? (Also, I suspect this will stop working if Huggingface goes out of business...)

Comment: Nice idea @ryan-codrai. But unfortunately the keywords are not necessarily in english. For instance, They can even be meaningless product codes.

Comment: @akx few-shot classification is Machine / Deep Learning approach where a model is asked to classify the input given very few training samples. Zero-shot classification is  few-shot classification with **ZERO** training samples.

Comment: @AKX I won't go into too much detail here about zero-shot NLP classification. That's something you can look up yourself in more detail.  While it's true that this will stop working if the Huggingface library is removed or changed that's also true of every python library. I've left the output of the code so that this answer can be understood even without being able to run the code.

Comment: @RyanCodrai The `transformers` library would remain on PyPI, I'm pretty sure, but the pipeline wouldn't be available. That's my concern here.

Comment: @ryan-codrai, I'm not looking for a "simple" solution but a standardized one. The problem seems standard so I should be expecting an existing package knowing how active the python community is.

Comment: @Neroksi I think you may be underestimating the difficulty of the problem you're trying to solve. You're asking for a deterministic frequency-based solution that's capable of understanding the importance of tokens based on the context in which they occur. I know this because you don't want to simply predict the class for which the largest number of related tokens occur.

Comment: @Neroksi You cannot expect a highly performant solution from token frequency without training a statistical model. To understand whether a token is an important signal we have to consider the tokens that come before and after it. The token "yellow" in the sentence "I ate a yellow fruit" is a strong signal for a banana because of the token "fruit" that follows. The token "yellow" in the sentence "I ate a yellow apple" is not a strong signal for "banana" because of the token "apple" that follows it. Context matters.

Comment: @ryan-codrai, nope ! I know that It's not simple, even if it seems. And I have no assuption about the algorithm except It should generalize and survive in the wild. For instance, I'm Ok with your transformer approach but I'm convinced we should find a way to let the model know about the keywords, otherwise performance won't be so good ...

Comment: @Neroksi Do you have labeled data?

Comment: @ryan-codrai  note that the dictionay is assumed to be quickly changing ... can you elaborate on how would you conduct a Naive Bayes classification approach in this scenario ?

Comment: @ryan-codrai Nope! But tons of unlabeled data are available (as usually).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248016/discussion-between-ryan-codrai-and-neroksi).